# Incomplete results retrieving birthdays using Facebook JavaScript API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve all the birthdays of a user friends using Facebook's Javascript API, however I'm getting incomplete results: some birthdays are fetched while others are not. And some of those which are not retrieved have their birthday on their facebook page. I have all the permissions necessary. Am I missing something?

The code I'm using just in case:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?fields=id,birthday', function(response) { console.log(response) });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely those friends (with missing birthday field) are not allowing apps to access their data.

Also it's a good idea to try the same call using server-side language or the Graph API explorer just to check that the results are consistent.